# Cocos2d CCSprite animation with multiple children

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

This question is purely conceptual as I have not yet created the sprite sheet I refer to. I'd appreciate suggestions for different approaches to my problem if you have them.

The sprite sheet I've created in my mind contains a collection of different human bodies, hair styles, shirts, pants, shoes, etc. The idea is that the user will choose what clothing to use with their player at runtime and each piece of clothing will be added to a CCSprite as a child.

The problem: These players would need to be animated, e.g. when the player is walking around. I had planned on adding a separate image for each clothing item to the sprite sheet for each possible frame of animation. When creating the CCAnimation object necessary for player movement, how can I create a CCSpriteFrame to add to the animation that contains all the necessary custom clothing items to match the original CCSprite? If you have another suggestion that would solve my problem, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is a strange problem and it wouldd be fun doing that. As per my understanding of Cocos2d, I would have taken different classes for all parts. Like my body is divided in 3 parts (Head,Body and Legs). I would have created different custom classes for them which are sublass of CCSprite and keep enums and animations for each of their types. In GameScene make different objetcs as child of main Sprite and animate all in sync.
Hope this helps. :)